# Validating ASP page input on button click

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

I'm completely new to ASP.Net programming *(coming from years of Windows programming)* and am having difficultly doing the simplest of things. I suspect that my entire approach is wrong - but I don't know.

I have a web page with *(say)* a textbox and a button. I want the user to enter an order number in the textbox, to validate it to check that it doesn't exist *(in my SQL database)* and to create it on the press of the button, after confirmation from the user. I don't want to create the order if it already exists. This would be **so** simple in a Winforms world, but seems all but impossible in an ASP.Net world.

I have a custom validator attached to my textbox, it calls my C# code and that looks up in the SQL database, if the record exists, it sets the ErrorMessage property of the validator. This is fine. I want the button so that, when clicked, it either says "correct errors" if there are any *(ie. the order number exists)* or asks "confirm create" if there are no errors and, if the user says ok, calls the "Click" event handler to create the order.

After much stumbling in the dark, I have this for my button:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function btnSave_Clicked() {
        if (Page_IsValid) {
            return confirm("Are you sure you want to create the order ?");
        } else {
            alert("Please correct the errors before attempting to save the order.");
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>

<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSave_Click" CausesValidation="true"
        OnClientClick="return btnSave_Clicked()" />

<asp:TextBox ID="txtPONumber" runat="server" MaxLength="20" AutoPostBack="true" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPONumber" Display="Dynamic"
                            ErrorMessage="The order number cannot be left blank." Text="*" ForeColor="Red" />
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPONumber" OnServerValidate="txtPONumber_ServerValidate"
                            Text="*" ForeColor="Red" />
```

...but even this *(the JavaScript)* doesn't work. Its the closest I've got, but while it works some of the time, not all. I presume that the validation can fire after the button click script has run.

I'm having trouble getting my head around what's happening where, and the page having no 'context' at all. Surely this is a very common requirement, validate a textbox and, if valid ask for user confirmation prior to performing some action.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think your main concern would be to understand the split between server-side (C#) and client-side (javascript) code. Although .NET makes it more difficult to understand by mixing everything up. basically, your approach is almost the good one, but you should drop at least for now the client-side validation and focus on server-side validation, especially as this specific validation needs server-side code as you want SQL queries. Later on you could maybe do this through AJAX so that the whole page doesn't reload, but let's keep it simple for now :-)

Comment: Would I be right in saying that if any of the validators report an error, the server-side button click never fires ? It seems to be the case - but that's not a great user interface (you click a button and nothing happens), hence my intention to say "sorry, you can't do that" when there are errors, and "do you want to do that" when there aren't. I haven't even dare look into the scenario of "there's no errors and the user clicks the button twice".

Comment: @BlackLight, right if any of the validator fails it will not allow to fire any other even, nor will allow you to postback.